# Regex for valid mysql table field

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm developing a php application that requires the creation of database fields, based on a source data. This data contains spaces, accents, characteres like slashes etc.

Right now I'm parsing this data, validating spaces, accents, but I would like to do it by a regular expresion that simply returns a valid database field name.

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I was told to do this, I would start reading the rules for defining a column name in MySQL.
You can read these rules here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html.

I have selected MySQL 5.7 but read the documentation for your targetd version.